# Guice TypeListener not notified about the injected class Type

Tags: java, guice

I have the following Guice module:

```
class MyModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bindListener(Matchers.any(), new TypeListener() {...});    
    }

    @Provides
    SomeClass createSomeClass(final Parameter param) {
        log(param.getValue()); <-- this gets logged
        ...
    }
}
```

What I found strange is that my `TypeListener` doesn't get notified about the `Parameter` type. Even though the provider is beign called and returns `SomeClass`. I also see the log statement so clearly the `Parameter` was injected by Guice.

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
    bind(Parameter.class);
    bindListener(Matchers.any(), new TypeListener() {...});    
}
```

I'm aware of [Untargetted bindings](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/UntargettedBindings) and the statement:

> An untargetted binding informs the injector about a type, so it may prepare dependencies eagerly.

I would still expect Guice to call the `TypeListener` for any type which is either explicitly *binded* or *injected* for the first time.

So do I need to make untargetted binding for such classes as a rule of thumb?

**NOTE:** marking the `Parameter` constructor with `@Inject` doesn't solve the problem.

**EDIT:**

The complete example (hope I din't leave too much garbage) is as follows:

```
public class TestGuice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector parentInjector = Guice.createInjector(new ParentModule());
        Injector childInjector = parentInjector.createChildInjector(new SubModule());

        childInjector.getInstance(Runnable.class).run();
    }

    static class ParentModule extends AbstractModule {

        @Override
        protected void configure() {

        }
    }

    static class SubModule extends  AbstractModule {

        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(SampleInjectedClass.class); // <-- Comment/uncomment here

            final TypeListener typeListener = new TypeListener() {
                public <I> void hear(TypeLiteral<I> type, TypeEncounter<I> encounter) {
                    System.out.println("Type: " + type.getRawType());
                }
            };

            bindListener(Matchers.any(), typeListener);
        }

        @Provides
        Runnable createRunnable(final SampleInjectedClass sampleClass) {
            return new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    sampleClass.test();
                }
            };
        }
    }

    static class SampleInjectedClass {
        public void test() {
            System.out.println("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

If the line is present the output is:

> Type: class com.barcap.test.TestGuice$SampleInjectedClass
>
> Type: class com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod
>
> Test

If I remove the line I get:

> Type: class com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod
>
> Test

I noticed that if the injector wasn't created via the `createChildInjector` code the `bind(...)` is not necessary.

Comment: The given code isn't enough to reproduce the problem.  I don't see anything particularly wrong with the posted code, how do you know the TypeListener isn't being called?

Comment: Please see the complete example attached

Comment: Okay now I understand what's happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Just-in-time bindings created for child injectors will be created in an ancestor injector whenever possible](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html#createChildInjector%28com.google.inject.Module...%29).  This means that, without the `bind(SampleInjectedClass.class);` line, the binding for `SampleInjectedClass` is created in the parent injector.  Since the parent injector doesn't have your `TypeListener`, it won't be triggered.

Comment: However, if you call `bind(SampleInjectedClass.class).asEagerSingleton()` the binding will be created and will trigger your `TypeListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your code? In my test on Guice 3, [I couldn't reproduce what you're seeing](http://pastebin.com/7udtKP07).

Also, from the [TypeListener docs](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/spi/TypeListener.html#hear%28com.google.inject.TypeLiteral%3CI%3E,%20com.google.inject.spi.TypeEncounter%3CI%3E%29), emphasis mine and typo sic:

> `public abstract void hear (TypeLiteral<I> type, TypeEncounter<I> encounter)`
>
> Invoked when Guice encounters a new type eligible for constructor or members injection. Called during injector creation **(or afterwords if Guice encounters a type at run time and creates a JIT binding)**.

Though all the rest of your dependencies will be called on the TypeListener immediately when the injector is created, [implicit ("just-in-time")](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/JustInTimeBindings) bindings will not.

However, based on my example above, it appears that when a parameter is included in a provider method, it is registered on the same listener immediately. Can you produce a short self-contained example that shows the behavior you're asking about?

Comment: Will try. I tried to extract the important part from more complicated example, it is possible I missed something obviously. One important thing might be I was using `childInjector`. Will extract the example as suggested and be back.